# How do you send an email from within an AIR Desktop Application?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, email, air

I am trying to allow to the user to send an email from within an AIR Desktop application.
At first I tried:

```
navigateToURL(newURLRequest("mailto:someone@example.comSubject=Hello&Body=SomeText");
```

But this opens up an empty tab in the default internet browser.

Then I tried to use a php file, I uploaded it on a server. PHP code is:

```
<?php
$to = ($_POST['recipientEmail']);
$subject = ($_POST['SenderName']);
$message = ($_POST['senderMesssage']);
$headers = "From: " . $_POST['senderName'] . " <" . $_POST['senderEmail'] .     ">\n";
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "answer=ok";
} 
else 
{
    echo "answer=error";
}
?>
```

and uploaded it on the following address:
    http://xespoofer.comxa.com/mail.php

The actionscript side is:

```
var myVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
myVars.senderName = settings.companyName;
myVars.senderEmail =String(settings.settingsXML.Setting.@senderEmail);;
myVars.senderMesssage = String(settings.settingsXML.Setting.@Message);
myVars.recipientEmail = String(settings.settingsXML.Setting.@email);

var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://xespoofer.comxa.com/mail.php");
myURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myURL.data = myVars;

var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
myLoader.load(myURL);
```

The actionscript code runs when a button is clicked. The problem is nothing happens. The email is not sent.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add some listeners to detect what is happening.
I just tried (using hard coded strings, you should replace to use your proper data):

```
var myVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
myVars.senderName = "name";
myVars.senderEmail =String("email@email.com");;
myVars.senderMesssage = String("Message");
myVars.recipientEmail = String("email2@email.com");

var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://xespoofer.comxa.com/mail.php");
myURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myURL.data = myVars;

var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
myLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
myLoader.load(myURL);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("completeHandler: ", URLLoader(event.target).data.toString());
}

function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace("progressHandler");
}

function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("ioErrorHandler");
}
```

And the `completeHandler` method outputs: "`answer=ok`". Debug it using your real data and check if you are passing the right values to `senderName`, `senderEmail`, `senderMessage` and `recipientEmail`.

Comment: I hard coded all the variables and I am getting the same result (answer = ok) but the email is still not being delivered.

Comment: Check your PHP code if you are receiving proper data and sending the e-mail. Because your ActionScript code seems to be okay.

Comment: Make sure the `senderEmail` is from the same domain as the mail server, or else it likely will get trapped as spam. Usually it's a better idea to let the server-side script use its own email address, and you might populate the reply-to with the sender's email instead.